# Take a string and return all occurrences of its first char with a '*'

Tags: python

I am trying to find out how to search through a string in python and return it where all occurrences of its first char are changed to a '*'. e.g. - 'babble' yields 'ba**le'. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I don't see why the votes-to-close, the question is well-defined, not  "too broad". It doesn't show effort, but that's a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is easier than figuring out why you would want to:

```
def asteriskify( string ):
   if len( string ) == 0: return ''   # corner case pointed out by smci
   return string[ 0 ] + string[ 1: ].replace( string[ 0 ], '*' )
```

Comment: a) Nice, except corner-case fail when len(s) == 0 or 1 . b) Never call your argument `string`, that masks the package of the same name.

Comment: @smci  good catch on length 0.  Length 1 is no problem.  And life's too short to worry about name collisions: they'll always happen, if not in the current version of Python, then in the next when new packages are added.

Comment: length 1 is still a bug, because `s[1:]` blows up with IndexError [EDIT: actually it's fine, it's just '']

Comment: `'a'[1:]` returns `''` without an IndexError for me in Python 2.x . I believe Python 3 allows it too.

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake. Anyway for speed, `if len(s) < 2: return s` :)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly tweaking @jez's neat solution to not blow up on the corner-cases with len(s) == 0 or 1:

```
def asteriskify(s):
    if not s: # was if len(s) < 2:
        return s
    else:
        return s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Yes. I would suggest you approach this by having a look at pythons string methods, as you will no doubt come across some that will help. Just remember what it is exactly that you want to do with the letters. I think this is better than just offering you up the code without you needing to do any research.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

using `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> def asteriskify(my_string):
...     if len(my_string)>1:
...         return my_string[0]+re.sub(my_string[0],"*",my_string[1:])
...     else: return my_string
... 
>>> asteriskify("bable")
'ba*le'
>>> asteriskify("babble")
'ba**le'
>>> asteriskify("b")
'b'
```

using  `map`, `lambda`:

```
>>> def asteriskify(my_string):
...     if len(my_string) > 1:
...         return my_string[0]+"".join(map(lambda x:"*" if my_string[0]==x else   x,my_string[1:]))
...     else: return my_string
... 
>>> asteriskify('babble')
'ba**le'
>>> asteriskify('b')
'b'
>>> asteriskify('baaabbb  ahdbb ccc')
'baaa***  ahd** ccc'
```